# what does "by order" here means?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Could you explain what "by order" means in the following passage?

> CURSE THREE
>
> AFTER CURSE THREE THE VICTIM DIES 
> *Given under my hand and* 
> *written in my* Blood 
> BY ORDER 
> THE AVENGER.
>
> L. P. Hartley, *The Go-Between*

I understand that the "given under my hand and written in my Blood" part modifies the "curse three", but what does "by order" mean? Does it mean "by the order of the avenger"?

Answer (score 1):

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/by_order) gives this:

> according to directions given by the proper authority.

By order (with the above meaning) used to be commonly seen on official notices, meaning that the instruction to do, or not do, something had been formally issued by an official body. So here, By order: The Avenger is intended to give extra weight to the warning. - @KateBunting

Comment: _By order_ (with the above meaning) used to be commonly seen on official notices, meaning that the instruction to do, or not do, something had been formally issued by an official body. So here, _By order: The Avenger_ is intended to give extra weight to the warning.